# Модификация стандартного функционала netty

Tags: java, netty

Есть два локальных сервера (BD server, Auth Server). Общение между ними реализовано с помощью netty 4.1.4 на приме/отправке объектов.
Столкнулся с трудностями объединить в одном вызове функции отправку и возвращение данных. К примеру:
1) Клиент хочет авторизоваться.
2) Вызывается функция проверки на сервере авторизации.

```
boolean tryAuth(String acc_name, String pass) {
    final Account account = CheckNonNull(acc_name, pass);
    return account != null;
}
```

3) В свою очередь функция CheckNonNull(par1, par2) отправляет данные DB серверу и возвращает полученный результат.

Собственно, вопрос - есть ли апи расширяющее функционал нетти для подобной реализации, или как это можно реализовать? (протобаф не предлагать, уже проходили)
P.S. обертка Observable в стрим, тоже не подходит

Comment: Не увидел в вашем описании проблемы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev функция CheckNonNull должна отправить запрос на сервер и вернуть полученные данные. Как это сделать - без понятия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было найдено решение с создания класса обертки над `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future<T>`

```
public <T> ResponseFuture Response(final T msg) {
    final ResponseFuture<T> responseFuture = new ResponseFuture<>();

    f.addListener((GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture>) future -> {
        f.channel().pipeline().get(DBServerHandler.class).setResponseFuture(responseFuture);
        f.channel().pipeline().get(DBServerHandler.class).WriteInfo(msg);
    });

    return responseFuture;
}
```