# Netty правильное принятие и обработка пакета

Tags: java, netty

У меня есть сервер и клиент.

Клиент отсылает пакет серверу.

В ответ он должен получить тот же пакет только уже с данными.

Проблема заключается в том что я создаю новый пакет когда он приходит обратно.
А мне же нужно после отправки пакета получить его обратно(уже с информацией) и продолжить работу с информацией полученной от сервера.

Пакет:

```
import io.netty.channel.Channel;

public abstract class Packet {

public abstract void readPacketData(PacketBuffer buf);

public abstract void writePacketData(PacketBuffer buf);

public abstract void processPacket(Channel channel, Runnable runnable);

public abstract void processPacket(Channel channel);
```

}

Вызов пришедшего пакета на клиенте и сервере одинаковы

```
  @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    Packet packet = (Packet) msg;
    packet.processPacket(ctx.channel());
}
```

Пакет который получает сервер.

```
public abstract class ProxyOnlinePacket extends Packet {
private int online;

public ProxyOnlinePacket() {}

@Override
public void writePacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    buf.writeIntLE(ConnectionState.getPacket_ID(this));
    buf.writeIntLE(this.online);
}

@Override
public void readPacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
}

@Override
public void processPacket(Channel channel) {
    Logger.info("Пришел запрос онлайна!");
    online = 200;//Пример.
    channel.writeAndFlush(this);
}
```

}

Пакет, который должен отправить клиент серверу.

```
public abstract class ProxyOnlinePacket extends Packet {
private int online;

public ProxyOnlinePacket() {}

@Override
public void writePacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    buf.writeIntLE(ConnectionState.getPacket_ID(this));
    buf.writeIntLE(this.online);
}

@Override
public void readPacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    online = buf.readIntLE();
}

@Override
public void processPacket(Channel channel) {
    System.out.print("Пакет пришел обратно!");
}
public int getOnline() {
    return online;
}
```

}

Но вот проблема. Я должен получить данные в том же месте где отправил этот пакет(что бы работать с полученными данными)

```
ProxyOnlinePacket onlinePacket = new ProxyOnlinePacket();

    Proxy.getInstance().sendPacket(onlinePacket);//Отправляю пакет серверу.

    //Я не понимаю как это сделать.
    System.out.print("Online: " + onlinePacket.getOnline());//Здесь я уже должен вывести данные которые пришли от сервера.
```

Как я понял. Мне нужно по другому вызывать полученный пакет. Не так как ниже.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    Packet packet = (Packet) msg;
    packet.processPacket(ctx.channel());
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719227/Модификация-стандартного-функционала-netty Просмотрите в этом вопросе мой же ответ, возможно это то что Вам нужно, послать реквест с последующим возвращением результата